# Groupby selected rows by a condition on a column value and then transform another column

Tags: python, pandas

This seems to be easy but couldn't find a working solution for it:

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,2,2,2],
                'B': [1,1,2,2,3],
                'C': [1,1,2,3,4]})

   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  2  2  3
4  2  3  4
```

I want to select rows based on values of column `A`, then groupby based on values of column `B`, and finally transform values of column `C` into sum. something along the line of this (obviously not working) code:

```
df[df['A'].isin(['2']), 'C'] = df[df['A'].isin(['2']), 'C'].groupby('B').transform('sum')
```

desired output for above example is:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  2  2  5
3  2  3  4
```

I also know how to split dataframe and do it. I am looking more for a solution that does it without the need of split+concat/merge. Thank you.

Comment: It might be easier if you split things up rather than trying to do it all in one line

Comment: I have thought about that solution. However, since I am going to run bunch of these queries, I feel like there should be an easier way to do it than splitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just

```
s = df['A'].isin([2])

pd.concat((df[s].groupby(['A','B'])['C'].sum().reset_index(),
           df[~s])
         )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  2  2  5
1  2  3  4
0  0  1  1
```

---

**Update:** Without splitting, you can assign a new column indicating special values of `A`:

```
(df.sort_values('A')
   .assign(D=(~df['A'].isin([2])).cumsum())
   .groupby(['D','A','B'])['C'].sum()
   .reset_index('D',drop=True)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  2  2  5
3  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not really. I need to check for values of column `A` rather than group by them, I update the example to cover that.

Comment: Thank you again. I was aware of this solution. Is there a way to do it without splitting?

Comment: Another solution as requested. I would personally follow the first solution btw.

Comment: Good one. I prefer splitting one too since I think that would be faster. I would leave the question open for a bit longer in case there is a shorter answer. If not, I will accept yours. Thank you.

Comment: Also I do not want to groupby `A` since the selection list is actually more than one value, maybe you can edit your post to replace minimum `A` value per group or something like that (or I can add edit if you do not mind). Nonetheless, this basically solves the problem.